# How to integrate sizzle into angular $element

Tags: angularjs, sizzle

Is it possible to use sizzle as selector engine for angular $element?

Our motivation is that Angular jQuery Lite does everything we need except the dom queries for IE 8+.
An example might be:

`angular.element('ul[some=example]').find('input:text')`

Or should we rather use a custom jQuery build?

Comment: Why not just include jQuery?

Comment: We won't use jQuery ajax, animation and so on

Comment: Makes sense. Well in this case you can easily use Sizzle for this. It provides all necessary API, so you can extend angular.element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS `.element()` implementation returns a `jQLite` object (or `jQuery` object) depending on what is available, but it **doesn't** support jQuery's Sizzle implementation.

In other words, `angular.element()` is for **creating elements** rather than finding elements.

Comment: Well I could find https://github.com/herschel666/angular-sizzle however it does not work for `.find` `.next` and so on

Comment: As you can see here: https://github.com/herschel666/angular-sizzle/blob/master/src/angular-sizzle.js#L33 this is just a simple wrapper for the sizzle engine. Sizzle itself has no .find() and .next() method either.

Comment: Sizzle provides a find function: `$(context).find(selector)` would be  `Sizzle(selector, context)`

Comment: Sorry you're right. However, I think your question is answered isn't it? :)

Comment: Well I was hoping for a better solution than "not possible" so I will keep it open for some more days - hopefully that's fine for you :)